# How come some properties are not showing up in the migration?

Tags: c#-8.0, entity-framework-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am running EF Core 3.1 in Visual Studio 2019.

I have two classes: PhoneNumber and PhoneNumberType.

```
 public class PhoneNumber : ValueObject
{
    public int Id { get; }

    [Phone]
    public string PhNumber { get; }

    //public int? PhoneNumberTypeId { get; private set; }

    public PhoneNumberType PhoneType { get; }
}

 public class PhoneNumberType : ValueObject
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
 }
```

In my DBContext.OnModelCreating I have (Connection is the principle Entity of PhoneNumber):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Connection>().OwnsMany(s => s.PhoneNumbers, a => a.HasOne(b => b.PhoneType).WithMany().HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Id));
```

However when I create the migration this is what is created:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "PhoneNumber",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ConnectionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Id1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                PhoneTypeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },

 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "PhoneNumberType",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
            }
```

Notice that the PhoneNumber.PhNumber and PhoneNumberType.Description are not in the migration.  Why not? What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I needed setters on the properties.